# Vuejs 2 include assets

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am just starting out with VueJS, and am trying to include an external JS library for use in my component.

I have downloaded the minified JS file and placed in my assets directory. How do I compile my component to include this library, so I can use it in my component code? I also wish to include CSS files from the assets directory.

I have searched the Vue docs and can't find an answer to my question, any help is much appreciated.

My guess so far is that I have to edit webpack file?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding an example of your config might help;

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you need to import/require the external file into to the vue component

```
component.js 

const external = require('../to/external_lib.min.js');

... declare Vue component as normal
```

for importing external CSS;
or say importing css into the component, you'll need to change your webpack config by adding `css-loader` and `style-loader`
(i.e. `npm i --save css-loader style-loader`);

afterwards in your `component.js`

```
component.js

const external = require('../to/external_lib.min.js');

import '../to/component.css';

... declare Vue component as normal
```

without more information as to say, your js file, or your project setup, i can not give more detailed information.